# A cross breed, Riley-Tyo-Classic riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My suffix is low calorie,
>
> You could probably find me in a special gallery,
>
> With three I am a type of test,
>
> Some of me were made in a contest,
>
> I come in many variations,
>
> None made of brie, but I can be found in many locations,
>
> I can play many roles such as a wide receiver, best buddy to a close friend,
>
> Or even be a base for a far-away frontier where people can ascend

## What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are

> a **satellite**.

```
My suffix is low calorie,
```

> "lite" is often how lo cal items are described.

```
You could probably find me in a special gallery,
```

> There are [exhibits](https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/applications-satellites) that show various [types](https://www.si.edu/exhibitions/satellites-and-sounding-rockets-3466) of [satellites](https://www.si.edu/spotlight/civilian-application-satellites).

```
With three I am a type of test,
```

> This Tyo-style clue says the first three letters are a type of test; **SAT** fits.

```
Some of me were made in a contest,
```

> SEDS apparently has done multiple contests, most recently the [2016-17 SSPI Satellite Design Competition](https://ukseds.org/get-involved/sspi-satellite-design-competition/)

```
I come in many variations,
```

> Indeed. There are many types of satellites, natural and artificial, for a whole array of uses.

```
None made of brie, but I can be found in many locations,
```

> The moon is a natural satellite, and is (speculation notwithstanding) not made of cheese.  Most planets in our system have moons, and some [exomoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exomoon) have been identified.

```
I can play many roles such as a wide receiver,
```

> Satellites are used for signal transmission and relay, and there are "satellite receivers" of various types.

```
best buddy to a close friend,
```

> The word satellite also means "a person who follows or serves another", or this may simply be referencing our own moon, with the Earth being our (very) close friend.

```
Or even be a base for a far-away frontier where people can ascend
```

> This perhaps is a reference to the ISS or similar, or maybe to part of a space elevator system.

Comment: Yup that is correct, good job explaining all of the parts.